# How can i match Fingerprint from sqlite data base?

Tags: android, pattern-matching, fingerprint, android-studio-2.2, android-fingerprint-api

I want to create one application which can match fingerprint form my server existing fingerprints, on my server side some fingerprints saved with the help of external fingerprint scanner. 
can i match with saved fingerprint?

Answer (score 1):

1. Match in database

You cannot match fingerprint in database, please read this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint_recognition

You have to match templates, thanks to a specific algorithm.
To match on server, you need AFIS solution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_fingerprint_identification

2. Extract fingerprint in Android or iOS

It's not possible to obtain fingerprint data (image or template) from Android or iOS except with an external fingerprint reader with specific SDK.

Comment: I have sample Fingerprint image from external Fingerprint scanner, and stored all the images in data base.

Comment: You cannot match fingerprint image, you have to extract template to match them, do you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint_recognition ?

Comment: @Vishal Is it useful ?